Unexpected token "BIGINT" while creating database (DB2 LUW)
This is a simple sql command that I want to run:
CREATE TABLE USERMNGR.AUTHORIZED_CLIENT (
    ID BIGINT  (8) DEFAULT J NOT NULL,
    AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_STATUS CHAR    (10) DEFAULT 'Y',
    CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR (40) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    NATIONAL_CODE CHAR    (16) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

It has some whitespaces but I don't think they pose any problems. Running the script using IBM Data Studio, DBeaver and the DB2 CLI will give this error:
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "BIGINT" was found following "ORIZED_CLIENT ( 
 ID".  Expected tokens may include:  "BINARY".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.33.31

I can't find where's the problem. I've created the database USERMNGR manually before running the script, and know that BIGINT is supported by DB2. Every unexpected token error that I've found on the internet had some issue that this command does not have. It's a simple CREATE TABLE. I even removed preceding USERMNGR. and it didn't change anything. I changed the BIGINT data type into INTERGER and it threw another error at me:
CREATE TABLE USERMNGR.AUTHORIZED_CLIENT (
    ID INTEGER  (8) DEFAULT J NOT NULL,
    AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_STATUS CHAR    (10) DEFAULT 'Y',
    CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR (40) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    NATIONAL_CODE CHAR    (16) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "(" was found following "LIENT ( 
 ID INTEGER".  Expected tokens may include:  "CHECK".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.33.31

And another try:
CREATE TABLE USERMNGR.AUTHORIZED_CLIENT (
    ID INTEGER DEFAULT J NOT NULL,
    AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_STATUS CHAR    (10) DEFAULT 'Y',
    CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR (40) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    NATIONAL_CODE CHAR    (16) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

And the error:
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "NOT" was found following "D INTEGER  DEFAULT J".  Expected tokens may include:  "<references_spec>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.33.31

I'm a newbie in DB2, know more about sql but I'm no pro there either. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

I've removed the (8) DEFAULT J from ID declaration, and it did create the table. However, this command was generated using razorsql from another DB2 database and it wasn't manually written. Also, there are many more tables and commands (the main script is 80MB) and I can't manually edit all of it.

Seems like a razorsql problem.

@jarlh for a paid product, it sure doesn't look very professional to make such mistakes. So this command is 100% syntactically wrong? If so, I have to use DB2 Data Studio or DBeaver to generate the scripts.

@lll_phr: I'd recommend notifying the maker of "RazorSQL" of these problems, so that he can fix them in his tool and so that others can benefit from bugs fixed in the future

@marc_s Of course, thanks for the recommendation! I just have to test it with other tools and be sure that the problem is RazorSQL, not the data or database configuration. After that, I'm gonna report the bug asap :D

So at the end, I wasn't sure if I did anything wrong or if the RazorSQL did something wrong. I noticed that the database I was generating script for had a different driver from the one I was executing the script on. I couldn't find the exact driver (Our group has limited access to it) but I could connect to it with DBeaver and LUW old (apparently version 8 and below) driver. I encountered some other problems regarding the different version of drivers there but I managed to do what I wanted to do.

It looks like you're encountering some syntax issues while trying to create a table in your DB2 database. Let's see if we can fix that!
CREATE TABLE USERMNGR.AUTHORIZED_CLIENT (
    ID BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_STATUS CHAR(10) DEFAULT 'Y',
    CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    NATIONAL_CODE CHAR(16) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

In this corrected answer:
I removed the size specification for BIGINT, as it's unnecessary.
Give it a shot, and let's see if it works. I'm not entirely sure if this will fix the problem, but it's worth a try.

Yeah that fixed the problem, thanks :D.  However, I've generated this script using RazorSQL and didn't write it manually.  In that script, all of the BIGINT data types have size specification (and the default non-number value). I think these tools may not create syntactically wrong scripts.
